# Type-Cast member of derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have a class M and many derived classes A:M, B:M, C:M

The derived classes A,B,C are obviously different, else they were not been declared.

M implements a member that needs to know the type of the calling class.

So, today I'm using an abstract member in M and individually override in each dervied class.

In M:

```
public abstract Do() {};
```

In A:

```
public override void Do()
{
    DoMore<A>();
}
```

In B:

```
public override void Do()
{
    DoMore<B>();
}
```

In C:

```
public override void Do()
{
    DoMore<C>();
}
```

Is there a way to implement `Do()` in `M` just once for all derived classes ? Something like:

In M:

```
public Do<T>() {
    DoMore<T>();
}
```

This does not work because `DoMore()` is casting on the derived class.

Comment: If `DoMore` needs to do something specific for each derived class why isn't it also abstract/virtual?

Comment: A "bigger" type shouldn't know any of its derived once. Are you sure a base class is what you actually need? Do you need specific members of your derived types?

Comment: Can you change `DoMore` method like `void DoMore(Type t)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you make the base class generic, you can make it "aware" of its derived type:

```
public class M<T> 
{
    public Do<T>() 
    {
        DoMore<T>();
    }
}

public class A : M<A> {...}
public class B : M<B> {...}
public class C : M<C> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible in case you create the

```
             DoMore method in the base class and make it abstract and override 
             in the child class so that appropriate method is called
```

but more or less it will be the 
                 same as overriding Do method which you have just move to parent class and made it non abstract.